# Nullpointerexception using Inputstream-Scanner

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner

I am currently working on an android app that takes the contents of a requested website and searches it for certain words.
I am unsure though how I can convert the InputStream into a String.
I'm a pretty unexperienced so I guess my code is a little ugly:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
String EanCode;
String FddbData;
InputStream stream;

public void Urlconnect() {                                                                   

    final Thread ConnectThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://fddb.info/db/de/suche/?udd=0&cat=site-de&search=" + EanCode);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream stream = (InputStream) connection.getContent();
                StreamToString();


            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    ConnectThread.start();

}
```

2:

```
    public void StreamToString() throws IOException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        sb.append(scanner.toString());
    }

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName());
    logger.info(sb.toString() + "bananeneis");

    FddbData = sb.toString();
}
```

}

This is the Error I am getting:

```
W/System.err:     at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:568)
    at com.example.prepper.MainActivity.StreamToString(MainActivity.java:22)
    at com.example.prepper.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:9)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Any Help is appreciated!

EDIT 2: Solved by removing **InputStream** in

```
 URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
 InputStream stream = connection.getContent();
 StreamToString();
```

Comment: My guess would be that  the field `stream` is `null`.

Comment: @Turing85 No, Stream is not null. That's what I put the logger there for. Also i checked that other question thread before and it didn't help me ._.

Comment: At `InputStream stream = (InputStream) connection.getContent();` you are declaring and initializing *local* variable named `stream`. Is it intentional? Just asking since in your `StreamToString()` method you seem to be using `stream` *field* (those are not same variables despite having same name which means that `stream` *field* probably still holds `null`).

Comment: The `logger`-part is never reached since the `Exception` is thrown before it is reached. Thus, these statements cannot provide any information. --- Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Java programming conventions have methods, fields, and variables start with a lower case letter (streamToString).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your `stream` to `StreamToString`. At the moment that method is operating on a different, unrelated variable that’s confusingly *also* called `stream`.

1. Change

   ```
   public void StreamToString() throws IOException {
   ```

   to

   ```
   public void StreamToString(final InputStream stream) throws IOException {
   ```
2. Change

   ```
   StreamToString();
   ```

   to

   ```
   String result = StreamToString(stream);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Try to make `InputStream stream;` as global variable. I can't see the `close()` method so insert it after `StreamToString();` method to close a opened stream, or insert a `close()` after while loop. Good luck :)

Comment: Java doesn’t have global variables.

Comment: Input stream already is global. Do you have any Idea how I could fix the NPE?

Comment: I had on mind "global variable" as variable created in class, no in method bro

Comment: @CrystalEngine7 check via console what will have you get from scanner, I had trouble with npe some time ago and that was caused by null variable returned.

Comment: @CrystalEngine7 try to make a `get` method which returning a search variable